# Implementing a method from Interface Java

Tags: java, implementation

Guys could you help explain me the last 2 lines please

`MenBook mbobject = (MenBook) other`

does it mean that mbobject is an object of the class Menbook? and what does the Other mean?

```
  public boolean moreExpensiveThan(Object other) {
  If(other == null)
    return false;
   else if (getClass() != other.getClass()) 
    return false;
   else {   MenBook mbobject = (MenBook) other;
        return (sellingPrice() >= mbobject.sellingPrice());
       }
```

Please note that `OrderedByPrice is an interface`

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to variable `mobject` (of type `MenBook`) the object `other` (of type `Object`), after checking that its type is of the correct one (`getClass() != other.getClass()`).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `MenBook` object called `mbObject` and you assign the object called `other` to it.

The `(MenBook)` in front of `other` means you are **casting** the object called `other` **to** a `MenBook` object.